# tmux shows weirdly encoded history on OSX

Tags: terminal, osx-lion, tmux, encoding, history

If I do the "history" command in tmux, I get a really weird result. Anyone got a hint on what to do to get normal output?

The output looks like this:

```
  477  ◆┬▒⎺▒└☃◆ 
  478  c▒├ ◆┬▒⎺▒└☃◆
  479  ec▒⎺ ◆┬▒⎺▒└☃◆
  48▮  ┴☃└ ·/↓├└┤│↓c⎺┼° 
  481  ├└┤│
  482  ┌⎽
  483  cd ┐⎺▒┼⎽/
  484  ┌e☃┼ ┐⎺▒┼⎽ ⎼┤┼
  485  ┌⎽
  486  ┌e☃┼ ▮1_e─┤▒┌☃├☃e⎽↓c┌┘ ⎼┤┼
  487  cd ↓↓
  488  ┌e☃┼ ┐⎺▒┼⎽ ⎼┤┼
  489  cd ┐⎺▒┼⎽/
  49▮  ┌e☃┼ ┐⎺▒┼ ⎼┤┼
  491  ┴☃└ ▮1_e─┤▒┌☃├☃e⎽↓c┌┘ 
  492  ▒☃⎽├⎺⎼≤
  493  ┌e☃┼ ┐⎺▒┼ ⎼┤┼
  494  ├└┤│ ┌⎽
  495  ├⎺⎻
  496  ▒☃⎽├⎺⎼≤
  497  e│☃├
  498  e│☃├
  499  ▒☃⎽├⎺⎼≤
S⎼e┼⎽↑M▒cB⎺⎺┐↑P⎼⎺↑2:· S⎺e⎼e┼$
```

I'm guessing it has to do with encoding.

I'm on a MacBook Pro in OSX Lion 10.7.5.

I'm using the Terminal app which has (among others) UTF-8 encoding enabled and UFT-8 under "International - Character Encoding:".

My shell is bash.

My tmux as per `tmux -V` is tmux 1.9a.

In my `~/.tmux.conf/`, I have

```
set-option -g          prefix ^Space
bind-key ^Space        send-prefix
unbind C-b
set-option -g          status-fg white
set-option -g          default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
set -sg                escape-time 1
set -g                 base-index 1
setw -g                pane-base-index 1
bind r                 source-file ~/.tmux.conf
set-window-option -g   utf8 on
set -g                 utf8
set -g                 status-utf8 on
```

My `languagesetup` is English, though I'm Danish and so is my keyboard layout :) This has only been a problem for me when `languagesetup` was not English - specifically, piping with my Danish pipe character `|` meant that bash would not recognise the command after the pipe if I wrote a space between it and the pipe, so I had to do e.g.

`echo $PATH |less`

rather than

`echo $PATH | less`

But as I said, I fixed this with `languagesetup`.

I'm really eager to get going with tmux, so I hope somebody knows how to fix it! :)

---

EDIT 1:

**CAUSE:**

The weird output was because I had ^N (the output from the key combination of Ctrl + n) in my history. The weird output can be intentionally forced if I press Ctrl + n followed by enter in tmux. I filed a ticket at tmux's SourceForge page in case it was a bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/137/
So, no ^N, no weird output!

---

EDIT 2:

For more interesting details, just look in the comments :)

---

EDIT 3:

After filing a bug report for the tmux developers at https://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/137/ , I have been told that the effect of ^N is not a bug. It is a feature from the olden pre-utf-8 days of hardware terminals, where developers used control characters to switch character sets in order to have access to a wider range of characters. ^N would "shift out", ^O would "shift in", that is, back to the original character set. Pressing ^O does not do anything for me in Terminal nor iTerm, and this is because ^O is remapped to "discard" - this can be seen by running `stty -a`. However, after having done ^N, you can run a shell script `printf '\x0F'`, which inputs the control character that ^O is supposed to produce, and the output will return to normal, as you "shift in".

Comment: Is there a command in your history, which might contain a special character that messes tmux' stdout up?

Comment: I just did `history -c history -w` to clear my history, and now it looks OK, so I think you were right. Looking through a backup of ~/.bash_history in Vim in a tmux session looks OK, but if I do `cat ~/bash_history.txt`, the result is all weird again. It must be one of those characters... Probably a Danish one :D Going to spend a little time tracking it down. Cheers!

Comment: `njjj`
This was the line that caused the weird output. 
I can tell from the characters in this comment box that `njjj` isn't interpreted as I see it in my terminal outside of tmux - in there, it's `^An^A^N^Ajjj`. I think it's from when I was experimenting with a new keymap for PREFIX in tmux - Ctrl+a, I guess, though I was also attempting Alt+a, but I guess the ^ means Ctrl.

Comment: For anyone interested, I tracked it down by doing head -n {linenumber} ~/bash_history.txt in tmux repeatedly, incrementing the linenumber exponentially until I received faulty input, then exit/enter tmux and continuing on, incrementing/decrementing in a binary search pattern and exiting/entering tmux when necessary.

Comment: nice :)). yes ^ stands for control :). Here's a source for what each control sequence means http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Comment: I tried replicating the keystrokes directly in tmux - apparently it is ^N that causes the weird output, as soon as I do this (which is Ctrl and n held down at the same time) and hit enter, the output is weird. 
      Srens-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Soeren$ ^N
      -bash: : c⎺└└▒┼d ┼⎺├ °⎺┤┼d
      S⎼e┼⎽↑M▒cB⎺⎺┐↑P⎼⎺↑2:· S⎺e⎼e┼$

Comment: Wow cool. Seems like `tmux` can't handle `0xe` (which is `^N` according to the source above) as output. I tested this with `echo -e '\xe' &> cn.hex; cat cn.hex` in tmux and I got the same results. Very nice!

Comment: Also if you ever come in touch with a demonic-tongue `tmux`, just type in `reset`. Or in `dt-tmux`: `⎼e⎽e├`

Comment: Thanks for your help in this detective work! Weird note: -e isn't in my `man echo`. Found an explanation online. Another note: I find it interesting that ^N in the list of asciii characters you linked to is " Shift Out, **alternate character set** ". Hmmm :)

Comment: And thanks for the tip on reset, works a treat! But what about the ^N not working (or working, if you desire demonic tongue) in tmux, should that be reported to the developers as a bug or something?

Comment: It definitely should. I'd wonder if nobody did already, though.

Comment: Alright, I filed a ticket at https://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/137/